# Incomplete \iftrue is valid input?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

Is LuaTeX beta-0.79.1 correct in thinking the following is valid input:

```
\iftrue
\bye
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An `\outer` macro is illegal only in a skipped branch of a conditional (and in arguments to macros, but it's not relevant here).

What happens when TeX processes a conditional in the form

```
<if><test><true text>\else<false text>\fi
```

where `<if>` stands for a primitive conditional and `<test>` is the list of tokens required by it for deciding about following the true branch or the false branch is:

- **the test turns out true**: remove `<if><test>` from the input stream
- **the test turns out false**: remove `<if><test>` and all tokens up to and including the matching `\else` (keeping track of conditionals in `<true text>`)

In both cases the conditional level is increased by one, to be decreased when `\else` or `\fi` will be expanded.

In your case you have

```
\iftrue\bye
```

that removes `\iftrue` and increases the conditional level; the `<test>` is empty for `\iftrue`. Then `\bye` is expanded and it causes the job to end. Since the conditional level is greater than 0 at this moment, a warning

```
(\end occurred when \iftrue was incomplete)
```

is issued.

This is standard behavior in original TeX: it doesn't go “all the way” to the matching `\fi`. An `\else` remaining in the case the conditional is true will skip the tokens up to and including the matching `\fi` and decrease the level. If no `\else` is found, the expansion of `\fi` decreases the level, leaving nothing in the input stream.

An `\outer` macro in a skipped branch will cause an error of “Incomplete conditional”, because TeX assumes something wrong happened. But non skipped tokens are expanded or executed normally.

Comment: An `\outer` macro is incorrect when it is scanned to the parameter too.

Comment: @wipet Yes, of course, but there's no macro with arguments here. I guessed that Angel thought an outer macro illegal also in that context. However I added a note about this, thanks for noting.